# Monero-Python connecting to Wallet error -13, can't find wallet

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-rpc, python

I have been trying for hours and get the basic python functions to work.  I am trying to run daemon locally and using monero-wallet-rpc to connect the daemon.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, it's been frustrating.
The python library is Monero-Python

My startup/init:

```
 monerod --rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0 --confirm-external-bind
```

Then:

```
monero-wallet-rpc --daemon-address 127.0.0.1:18081 --rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0 \
--rpc-bind-port 18088 --confirm-external-bind --wallet-dir <wallet_pass> \
--password <mypass> --disable-rpc-login
```

It successfully starts up with output:

```
This is the RPC monero wallet. It needs to connect to a monero
daemon to work correctly.

Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.3.1-release)
Logging to c:\Program Files\Monero GUI Wallet\monero-wallet-rpc.log
2024-01-31 01:33:51.986 I Binding on 0.0.0.0 (IPv4):18088
2024-01-31 01:33:52.173 W Starting wallet RPC server
```

The python code is simple:

```
from monero.daemon import Daemon
from monero.wallet import Wallet
from monero.backends.jsonrpc import JSONRPCWallet

daemon = Daemon(host="127.0.0.1", port=18081)
print(daemon.height())

wallet = Wallet(port=18088)
print(wallet.address())
```

When I run this, it crashes at the wallet line giving the error:

```
JSON RPC error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": -13,
    "message": "No wallet file"
  },
  "id": 0,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It only seemed to work when I moved the wallet key/files to local directory.  It did not work with --wallet-dir.  My wallet is stored on different drive.